# Linking value to dates in excel

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Is it possible that I put formula in Daily Points column which
will compare Work Date column with Game Date column and if it is
matched to put Points column value in Daily Points column for 
corresponding date. For example for Work Date column A3, A4, A5, A6 
and A7 which is 1/3/2006 I want the value from Points column which is in line with 1/3/2006 from Game Date column. Something like bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Standard VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A3,E:F,2,FALSE)
```